# How to return argument datatype from sql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

PostgreSQL 12.2+ function is defined as

```
create FUNCTION torus(eevarus text) returns text immutable AS $f$ 
 select translate( $1, U&'\00f8\00e9', U&'\0451\0439' );
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL ;
```

This function is called as CHAR(n) or text columns like

```
create temp table test (
charcol char(10),
textcol text );

insert into test values ('test', 'test');

select torus(charcol), torus(textcol), charcol
```

torus(charcol) returns text column and loses original column width. How to force torus() to return argument type:

if char(n) column is passed as argument, torus() should also return char(n) data type.
I tried to use bpchar instead on text

```
create or replace FUNCTION torusbpchar(eevarus bpchar) returns bpchar immutable AS $f$ 
 select translate( $1, U&'\00f8\00e9', U&'\0451\0439' );
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL ;
```

but `torusbpchar(charcol)` still returns text data type.

npgsql DataReader is used to get data.

I tried

```
create temp table test (
charcol char(10) );
insert into test values ('test');
select rpad ( torus(charcol),  length(charcol) )
FROM Test
```

but length returns invalid value 4. How to get column width (10) ?

**Update**

I tried Adrian solution from comment

```
create or replace FUNCTION torus(eevarus text ) returns text immutable AS $f$
select translate( $1, U&'\00f8\00e9', U&'\0451\0439' );
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL ;

create or replace function public.ColWidth(p_namespace text, p_table text, p_field text)
    returns int as $f$
select atttypmod-4 from pg_namespace n, pg_class c, pg_attribute a
         where n.nspname = p_namespace and
             c.relnamespace = n.oid and
             c.relname = p_table and
             a.attrelid = c.oid and
             a.attname = p_field;
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL ;

create table public.test ( charcol char(10) );
insert into test values ('test');
select rpad ( torus(charcol),  colwidth('public', 'test', 'charcol') )
FROM Test
```

at this worked. In this best solution?

How to remove p_namespace  parameter from colwidth()? ColWidth() should return column width in first search_path table just like

```
 select ... from test
```

finds table test.

Comment: Not sure why you expect a returned value to change it's type?  You asked for `text` to be returned and that is what you got. You could do `torus(charcol)::char(10)`, but I am not sure that really gets you anything?

Comment: torus() is used in generic scripts for different tables and databases where its parameter width is not known.  `torus(char12column)` should return `char(10)` type, `torus(char12column)` `char(12)` type. I tried `torus(genericcharcolumn)::char(sizeof(genericcharcolumn))`  but `sizeof` is not supported by Postgres. How to implement sizeof() function?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I updated question and added new testcase to end. It looks like length returs only text length. How to get column size?

Comment: Asked and answered on *pgsql-general* mailing list here [Argument data type](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1185464.1665759357%40sss.pgh.pa.us). You can't get that from the function argument. The question is why does it matter?

Comment: I should have been clearer, you can not get that information directly from the argument. You can do a look up on [pg_attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) and find the value for `atttypmod` for the column. Note that value is the actual column width + 4, so for your `char(10)` it would show up a `14`.

Comment: This is good solution. You can wrote it as answer. I updated question with it. How to remove schema parameter from colwidth() function?